# EF to ADO.NET transition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ado.net, dapper

Need suggestion for migration few modules of asp.net mvc 3 application:
Right now we are using EF with POCO classes, but in the future for some performance driven modules we need to move to ADO.NET or some other ORM tool (may be DAPPER.NET).

The issue we are facing as of now is: our views dependent on Collection classes getting loaded through EF, what strategy should i used for these entity classes to be get loaded exactly the same way as by EF with some other ADO.NET or ORM tool.

What i want is to be able to switch between EF & ADO.NET with minimum of change at data access layer, as i don't want my Views to get effect by that.

Comment: yes DAPPER.NET, thanks for correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Repository Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to hide the implementation of your data access layer.  The Repository will return the same POCO's and have the same operations contracts no matter what data access layer you are using underneath the hood.  Now this works fine if you are using real POCO's that do not have virtual methods for lazy loading in them. You will need to explicitly handle loading of dependent collections on entities to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

What I've seen so far, a seamless transition from one ORM/DAL to another is an illusion. The repository pattern as suggested by Kevin is a great help, a prerequisite even (+1). But nonetheless, each ORM has a footprint in the domain layer. With EF you probably use virtual properties, maybe data annotations or, easily forgotten, a validation framework that easily fits in (and dismiss others that don't). You may rely on EF's ability to map across join tables. There may be things you *don't* (but would like to) do because of EF.

(Not to mention tools that execute scaffolding on top of an EF context. That would make the lock-in even tighter.)

Some things I might do in your situation (forgive me if I'm stating the obvious for you)

- Use EF optimally. (Best mappings, best associations, ...) Preparing for the future is good, but it easily degenerates into the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) pattern.
- Become proficient in linq + EF: there are many ways to needlessly kill performance with EF. Suppose EF is good enough!
- Keep looking for alternatives for high performance, like using stored procedures, parallellization, background processing, and/or reducing data volumes, and choose one when the requirements (functional and non-functional) are clear enough.
- Maybe introduce an abstraction layer with DTO's that serve your views now, and in the future can be readily materialized by another ORM or ADO.
- Expose POCO's as interfaces, which can be implemented by other objects later.

Comment: Thanks GertArnold for detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

### Just to add to both of these answers...

I always structure my solution into these basic projects:

- **Front end** (usually asp.net MVC web app),
- **Services/Core** with business processes,
- **Objects** with application model POCOs and communication interfaces - referenced by all other projects so they serve as data interchange contracts and
- **Data** that implements repositories that return POCO instances from *Objects*
- Front end references Objects and Services/Core
- Services Core references Objects and Data
- Data references Objects
- Objects doesn't reference any of the others, because they're the domain application model

If front end needs any additional POCOs I create those in the front end as view models and are only seen to that project (ie. registration process usually uses a separate type with more (and different) properties than `Objects.User` entity (POCO). No need to put these kind of types in *Objects*.

The same goes with data-only types. If additional properties are required, these classes usually inherit from the same *Objects* class and add additional properties and methods like generic `ToPoco()` method that knows exactly how to map from data type to application mode class.

### Changing DAL

So whenever I need to change (which is as @GetArnold pointed out) my data access code I only have to provide a different Data project that uses different library/framework. All additional data-specific types etc. are then part of it as well... But all communication with other layers stays the same.

Instead of creating a new *Data* project you can also change existing one, by changing repository code and use a different DAL in them.

Comment: Thanks Robert we actually structured the project in same manner.